# bounds on normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proof of upper-tail inequality for standard normal distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28751/proof-of-upper-tail-inequality-for-standard-normal-distribution)
>   [Proof that $x \Phi(x) + \Phi'(x) \geq 0$ $\forall x$, where $\Phi$ is the normal CDF](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66958/proof-that-x-phix-phix-geq-0-forall-x-where-phi-is-the-normal)

Let $X$ be a normal $N(0,1)$ randon variable. 
Show that $\mathbb{P}(X>t)\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}t}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}$, for $t>0$.

Using markov inequality shows that $P(X>t)\le \frac{\mathbb{E}(X)}{t}$ but I dont know how to bound the expected value

Comment: Suppose that $t>0$ but very close to $0$. Then $P(X>t)$ is very close to $1/2$. But the right-hand side is about $0.4$ when $t$ is very near $0$. The question needs to be modified somewhat.

Comment: i missed a t at the denominator

Comment: In fact, this question has [been added to the faq](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions).

Answer (score 13):

The following argument is a standard one that can be used far more generally.

$$P(X>t)=\int_t^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}\,dx.$$
We are integrating from $x=t$ to infinity. So over the region of integration,  $x \ge t$, and therefore $\frac{x}{t}\ge 1$.  It follows that
$$\int_t^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}\,dx<  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}t}\int_t^\infty xe^{-x^2/2}\,dx.$$

Now we can integrate explicitly. An antiderivative of $xe^{-x^2/2}$ is $-e^{-x^2/2}$, and therefore
$$\int_t^\infty xe^{-x^2/2}\,dx=e^{-t^2/2},$$
which yields the desired result.

**Comment**: "General" inequalities, such as those of Markov (and therefore Chebyshev) are often much too weak to prove reasonably sharp bounds for specific distributions. In this case, if we apply the Markov Inequality *directly* to $X$, we conclude that $P(|X|>t) \le \frac{1}{t}E(|X|)$. The expectation of the absolute value of the standard normal is an easily computed *constant*.  So the bound we get from applying the Markov Inequality directly to $X$ is of the form $\frac{K}{t}$.  For large $t$, this is enormously larger than the truth, since it entirely misses the rapidly decaying $e^{-t^2/2}$ term.

Comment: how can i assume $x\ge t$??

Comment: We are integrating from $x=t$ to infinity. So *over the interval of integration*, we have $x \ge t$.  I have added this line to the post for clarity.

Comment: And indeed the question about $x \geq t$ is also asked in the discussion on this problem in the faq!!

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate: Repetition, or essential repetition, is very frequent on StackExchange.  But often it is easier to answer a question than to search for close relatives.  In this case, the question in fact started out different, because of the OP's inadvertent omission of the $t$ in the denominator.