# Inequality about normal distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proof that $x \Phi(x) + \Phi'(x) \geq 0$ $\forall x$, where $\Phi$ is the normal CDF](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66958/proof-that-x-phix-phix-geq-0-forall-x-where-phi-is-the-normal)

Let Z be a standard normal random varible. How to prove that:

$$P(Z>t)>\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{t}{t^{2}+1}e^{-\frac{t^{2}}{2}} $$

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: I recommend closure as a duplicate of many previous questions e.g. [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/28751/15941)

Comment: Thanks. And I have edited my question to another part of my question. Could you have a look?

Comment: In the future, it's better not to edit a question to change it to a different question.  It causes confusion with comments, votes, etc that are no longer relevant.  You should ask a new question instead.