# Need help in finding a probability such that this limit goes to 0

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I need to find a Random variable X such that
$\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{t^2}{\text{Var}X} \mathbb{P}(|X-\mathbb{E}X|\geq t) = 0$. I do understand that I can, for simplicity look at the case where the variance is 1 and the expected value is 0, simplifying it to $\lim_{t\to\infty} t² \mathbb{P}(|X|\geq t) = 0$. But I can't seem to find an example.
Does anyone here know a solution?

Comment: Concentration inequalities may help you : https://ai.stanford.edu/~gwthomas/notes/concentration.html

Comment: Or take a gaussian rv : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74151/proof-of-an-estimate-for-the-tail-of-a-normal-distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume $\mathbb EX=0$ then all you'll need to find is a random variable $X$ having moments of order greater than $2$. Markov's inequality tells you that $$\mathbb P[|X|\geq t]\leq \frac{\mathbb E|X|^{2+\alpha}}{t^{2+\alpha}}$$ and hence $$\frac{t^2}{\text{Var}(X)}\mathbb P[|X|\geq t] \leq \frac{t^2}{\text{Var}(X)}\cdot\frac{\mathbb E|X|^{2+\alpha}}{t^{2+\alpha}}=C\cdot t^{-\alpha}\to 0$$ as $t\to\infty$.

You will probably know many such random variables.

Comment: For instance, any bounded random variable (with positive variance) will do.