# Upper-tail inequality for t-distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, distribution-tails

I am interested in upper tail bounds (or bounds on deviation from the mean) for t-distribution with n degrees of freedom (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student's_t-distribution)

A bound that is of the form similar to the tail bound for standard normal distribution 
[Proof of upper-tail inequality for standard normal distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28751/proof-of-upper-tail-inequality-for-standard-normal-distribution) would be great.

Does anyone know where to find such a result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(1+t^2/n)^{-(n-1)/2} = -\frac{(n-1)}{2}(1+t^2/n)^{-(n+1)/2}\frac{2t}{n} = -\frac{(n-1)}{n}\cdot t \cdot (1+t^2/n)^{-(n+1)/2}$,
the method used by @cardinal in deriving a [bound on the upper tail probabilityof the 
normal distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/28754/15941) seems
to work here as well.  We have
$$\begin{align*}
P\{X > x\} &= \int_x^{\infty} \frac{c}{\left(1 + \frac{t^2}{n}\right)^{(n+1)/2}}
\mathrm dt\\
&\leq \int_x^{\infty}\frac{t}{x} \frac{c}{\left(1 + \frac{t^2}{n}\right)^{(n+1)/2}}
\mathrm dt\\
&= \frac{c}{x}\cdot\frac{n}{n-1}
\left[-(1+t^2/n)^{-(n-1)/2} \right|_x^{\infty}\\
&= \frac{n}{n-1}\cdot \frac{1}{x}\cdot 
\frac{c}{\left(1 + \frac{x^2}{n}\right)^{(n-1)/2}}
\end{align*}$$