# Prove that $X_n \sim N(0,\frac{1}{n})$ converges in probability to 0

Tags: probability, improper-integrals, normal-distribution, distribution-tails

**Problem**

Prove that $X_n \sim N(0,\frac{1}{n})$ converges in probability to 0.

**Discussion**

There a [problems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1035486/showing-that-x-n-n0-a-n-converge-to-0-when-a-n-to-0-sufficiently-f) similar to this question, but I want to ask specifically about the convergence of an integral that arises in the solution.

**Attempt**

Let $\epsilon>0$. To show $X_n \overset{p}{\to} 0$, we must show $P(|X_n| > \epsilon) \to 0$.

$$
\begin{align}
P(|X_n|>\epsilon) 
&= P(X_n>\epsilon) + P(X_n < -\epsilon)\\
&= P(Z>\epsilon\sqrt{n}) + P(X_n<-\epsilon\sqrt{n})
\end{align}
$$
where $Z$ is the standard normal distribution. Thus we want to show
$$P(|X_n|>\epsilon)=\int_{\epsilon\sqrt{n}}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}\text{dx}
+
\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon\sqrt{n}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}\text{dx}\to 0$$

I understanding intuitively that these integrals should converge to zero, but how can I show rigorously that they go to zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the tail bound for a standard normal random variable:
$$
\int_x^\infty \exp(-y^2/2)\,dy \le x^{-1}\exp(-x^2/2),
$$
which can be proved changing variables $y = x + z$ and using $\exp(-z^2/2) \le 1$.

Comment: I am selecting this as my answer because it directly shows how to work with the integral, which is what I was specifically asking about. The other answers also offer great solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Your integrals contain spurious instances of $\sqrt n$. You are evaluating $P(|Z|>\epsilon\sqrt n)$ where $Z$ is standard normal, so the integrand should not involve $\sqrt n$. Anyhow, you can prove $P(|Z|>\epsilon\sqrt n)\to0$ rigorously using Markov's inequality.

Answer (score 2):

$$E[X_n]=0$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\mathrm{Var}[X_n]=0$$

This is a necessary and sufficient condition for

$$X_n\xrightarrow{L^2}0$$

Convergence in $L^2$ implies convergence in probability