# Show an estimate of "tail" of normal cdf for large $x$.

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

> Lemma (Feller volume 1, 175p): As $x \to \infty$ 
>   $$1- \Phi(x) \sim x^{-1} \phi(x);$$
>   more precisely, the double inequality 
>   $$ (x^{-1} - x^{-3}) \phi(x) < 1- \Phi(x) < x^{-1}\phi(x)$$
>   holds for every $x > 0$.
>
> Proof: Obviously 
>   $$(1-3x^{-4}) \phi(x) < \phi(x) < (1+x^{-2})\phi(x).$$ 
>   The members are the negatives of the derivatives of those in the the second display in the lemma, and this follows by integration between $x$ and $\infty$.

$\sim$ indicates that the ratio between both sides converges to $1$ as $x$ tends to infinity. $\Phi$ and $\phi$ denotes normal cdf and pdf, respectively. In the proof, the first inequality holds since $1-3x^{-4} < 1 < 1+ x^{-2}$ and $\phi(x)>0$ for all $x$. When I integrate $\phi(x)$ between $x$ and $\infty$, I can get $1- \Phi(x)$. But, I am not sure how the integration of the other sides $(1-3x^{-4}) \phi(x)$ and $(1+x^{-2})\phi(x)$ results in  $(x^{-1} - x^{-3}) \phi(x)$ and  $x^{-1}\phi(x)$, respectively. I am also wondering how the inequality in the lemma implies the first display in the lemma.

I would appreciate if you give some help.

Comment: Integrate by parts. You may see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1135749/integral-inequality-of-exponent).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof of upper-tail inequality for standard normal distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28751/proof-of-upper-tail-inequality-for-standard-normal-distribution)