# Direct computation of $\operatorname{log}(\operatorname{cdf})$ for a normal distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, numerical-methods, normal-distribution

This question is linked to the normal distribution for a random variable. The probability density function (pdf) is expressed as:

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\, e^{-\frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}
\end{equation}

and the cumulative distribution function (cdf) is expressed as:

\begin{equation}
\frac12\left[1 + \operatorname{erf}\left( \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\right)\right]
\end{equation}

pdf or cdf functions might take extremely low values. When computing logarithm of pdf,

\begin{equation}
- \operatorname{log}(\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}) - \frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}
\end{equation}

is used directly, instead of first computing eq. 1, then taking the log.

Currently I compute the log of the cdf by first computing eq. 2, then taking its log. This creates numerical underflows in my program. I would like to compute the log directly, using a formula similar to eq. 3.

Is it possible ?

Comment: I think this depends on what your numerical problem is: is it full underflows (numbers going below $2^{-1024}$) or is it roundoff errors (numbers on the order of $1$ getting added to numbers on the order of $2^{-53}$)? The solutions to these two kinds of problems are rather different.

Comment: It is a bit of both. I need to add various log. The majority of which are close to 0., but some are under 1.7E- 308, which is the limit of the double type I use to compute the cdf. When I compute the sum I get $-\infty$.

Comment: When adding numbers of enormously varying magnitude, it's generally a good idea to find the summand of largest magnitude, divide all the terms by that, add them, and then multiply by what you divided by.

Comment: I do this in other part of the code. The problem here is that can not even compute the value of log(cdf).

Comment: You can't compute individual summands? How small should your actual *answer* be, more or less? It seems that if you can't compute individual summands and all of your summands have the same sign then your answer might not even be a floating point representable number. In this case you would need to use a higher precision arithmetic library to do anything.

Comment: I can sum logs and get values like -100000 for example. The problem is that I must be able to distinguish between near 0 and 0 probabilities. If I can not compute log(cdf) directly, I will have to use tricks like considering a cdf inferior to 1.7E- 308 as 1.7E- 308, and then forcing log(cdf) = log(1.7E- 308) = -708 . I wanted to avoid this and compute the real value of log(cdf) directly.

Comment: The problem is that you have log of an integral, which is like log of a sum, and which therefore has no simple algebraic tricks for its calculation. (By contrast the log of a product, like the log of the pdf in your question, has a simple algebraic trick to help us calculate it.) About the best thing you can do with the log of a sum is to try to write it as $\log(X+x)=\log(X)+\log(1+x/x) \approx \log(X)+x/X$, where $X$ is "big" and $x$ is "small". So in estimating $\log(P(X \leq a))$, you might choose $b$ so small that $\frac{P(X \leq b)}{P(b \leq X \leq a)}$ is less than some tolerance.

Comment: (Cont.) and then replace $P(X \leq a)$ with $P(b \leq X \leq a)$.

Comment: Another idea: when your probabilities get small, approximate the logarithm using http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28751/proof-of-upper-tail-inequality-for-standard-normal-distribution Then try to analytically see how bad your errors are.