# Upper bound inequality cumulative normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28751/proof-of-upper-tail-inequality-for-standard-normal-distribution) post, I found for $X \sim N(0,1)$, $x > 0$ the result that

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\big(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^3}\big)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \leq P(X>x) \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{1}{x}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}.
\end{align}

Now, an even stronger upper bound has to hold, namely
\begin{align}
P(X>x) \leq e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}.
\end{align}
For $x \geq 1$ this is obvious. However, it seems to be rather difficult to show that this inequality does hold for $0<x<1$. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(X > x) = P(e^{\lambda X} > e^{\lambda x})$ for all $\lambda$.

Now by Markov's inequality,
\begin{align}
P(e^{\lambda X} > e^{\lambda x}) &\leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda X}]}{e^{\lambda x}} \\
&=e^{\frac{\lambda^2}{2} - \lambda x}.
\end{align}
So for $\lambda = x$,
\begin{align}
P(X > x) \leq e^{\frac{x^2}{2}-x^2} = e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}.
\end{align}