# how to find area under normal distribution curve

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, area

> Find out the area in percentage under standard normal distribution curve of random variable $Z$ within limits from $-3$ to $3$.

my try: probability density function of standard normal distribution is $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$
now the area under standard normal distribution curve ($-3\le x\le3$),
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-3}^3e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\ dx$$
$$=2\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^3e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\ dx$$ 
$$=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^3e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\ dx$$
$$=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\ dx-\int_{3}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\ dx\right)$$
$$=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(\frac 12-\int_{3}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\ dx\right)$$

i got stuck here, i don't have any clue to solve above integral. please help me to solve it or give some other method to find the area under the curve.

Comment: There is no closed form for the cumulative distribution function of a standard normal.  You will need to use [tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table), or a [computer function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Normal.html), or an [approximation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28751/proof-of-upper-tail-inequality-for-standard-normal-distribution).

Comment: Yes, you can use a Standard Normal Table to find the area

Answer (score 1):

Because the standard normal CDF $\Phi$ cannot be written in closed form, numerical answers depend on numerical integration (printed tables or statistical software).

In R statistical sofware, $\Phi$ is `pnorm` so `pnorm(1)` gives 
$\Phi(1) = P(Z \le 1) = 0.8413,$ where $Z \sim Norm(0,1).$

```
pnorm(1)
## 0.8413447
```

The specific answer to your question is $\Phi(3) - \Phi(-3),$ which gives 99.7%.

```
pnorm(3) - pnorm(-3)
## 0.9973002
```

Here is a graph, from which you might be able to read some probabilities with 1 or 2-place accuracy.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. There is no elementary antiderivative to evaluate the considered area, but a special function has been designed and studied,

> $$
> \text{erf}(t):=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^te^{-x^2}\ dx,\qquad t \in \mathbb{R},
> $$

giving here
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-3}^3e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\ dx=\text{erf}\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}\right)
$$ and $\text{erf}(\cdot)$ is implemented in all CAS.