# Proof concerning standard normal random variable

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Let $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $\epsilon > 0$. I would like to prove the following $$\mathbb{P}(Y \geq \sqrt{2 \ln{\frac{2}{\epsilon}}} - \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2 \ln{\frac{2}{\epsilon}}}}) \leq \epsilon.$$

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you already tried some [Chebyshev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) techniques ?

Comment: I did, however was unable to come up with the proof using Chebyshev inequality.

Comment: In this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28751/proof-of-upper-tail-inequality-for-standard-normal-distribution/69417#69417) there is an iterative method with integration by parts to compute upper and lower bounds for the tail probabilities.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for!