# $\int_{a}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2} dx$

Tags: integration

**Question**
If $a>0$, show that $$\int_a^\infty e^{-t^2} \mathrm{d}t = \frac{e^{-a^2}}{2a}\left(1-\frac{1}{2a^2}+f(a)\right)$$ where $0<f(a)<\displaystyle\frac{3}{4a^4}$

My approach:
Applying integration by parts twice,
$$\int_a^\infty e^{-t^2} \mathrm{d}t=\frac{1}{2}\int_{a^2}^\infty e^{-p}p^{-1/2} \mathrm{d}p\\=\frac{e^{-a^2}}{2a}\left(1-\frac{1}{2a^2}\right)+\frac{3}{8}\int_{a^2}^\infty e^{-p}p^{-5/8} \mathrm{d}p$$
**Observation**

1. $p>a^2\\\implies 0<e^{-p}<e^{-a^2}\\\implies 0<e^{-p}p^{-5/2}<e^{-a^2}a^{-5}$
2. $p>a^2\\\implies 0<e^{-p}<e^{-a^2}\\\implies 0<e^{-p}p^{-1/2}<e^{-a^2}a^{-5}\\\implies 0<e^{-p}p^{-1/2}p^{-2}<e^{-a^2}a^{-5}p^{-2}\\\implies 0<\int_{a^2}^\infty e^{-p}p^{-5/2} \mathrm{d}p<e^{-a^2}a^{-1}\int_{a^2}^\infty p^{-2} \mathrm{d}p\\\implies 0<\int_{a^2}^\infty e^{-p}p^{-5/2} \mathrm{d}p<e^{-a^2}a^{-3}$

After applying integration by parts twice, I don't know where to go?

Any kinds of help will be appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: Could you, please, rotate the picture?

Comment: I wonder what is $+\infty\infty$...

Comment: @user12986714, a typo. One can easily edit the title after seeing the task. It happens.

Comment: @user12986714 Sorry , I copied the integration mathjax from another post.

Comment: I can't rotate my computer and I already have a lack of space on it.

Comment: I could rotate the image, if I were able to edit...

Comment: If you can't post a right-side up picture, then type your question.  Images are discouraged on this site anyway.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.

Comment: @saulspatz should i delete this post ?

Comment: No, I'm not suggesting that.  Just bear it in mind for future posts.  Now that the someone has rotated the image, the post is legible.

Comment: Do you know about double integration?

Comment: I edited the post, I rotated the image. I need an approval now.

Comment: Thank you @Axel

Comment: Do you know about double integration ..?

Comment: @Saket Gurjar no

Comment: Here's a related question that may be useful.  It doesn't go all the way to solving your problem, but perhaps it will give you some ideas. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28751/proof-of-upper-tail-inequality-for-standard-normal-distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continue your solution by applying integration by parts one more time
$$\int_{a^2}^{\infty}e^{-x}x^{-5/2}\,dx=\frac{e^{-a^2}}{a^5}-\frac 52\int_{a^2}^{\infty}e^{-x}x^{-7/2}\,dx<\frac{e^{-a^2}}{a^5} $$
Hence,
$$0<\frac 38\int_{a^2}^{\infty}e^{-x}x^{-5/2}\,dx<\frac{3e^{-a^2}}{8a^5} $$
and now you can conclude.