# Proving normal CDF bounds

Tags: integration, normal-distribution

I would like to prove the following bound:

$$\int_x^\infty e^{-y^2/2}\,dy\le \frac1x e^{-x^2/2}$$

Is it valid to say that $$x^{-1}\exp(-x^2/2) = \int_{x}^{\infty} \left(\frac{y^2+1}{y^2}\right)\exp(-y^2/2)\,dx \geq \int_{x}^{\infty}\exp(-y^2/2)\,dx\,?$$

If so, why do most solutions online and in textbooks (like [this](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter4/4_2_6_solved4_2.php)) avoid using this method? I have a feeling i'm doing something wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you justify your first identity ?

Comment: Duplicate of [Proof of upper-tail inequality for standard normal distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28751/proof-of-upper-tail-inequality-for-standard-normal-distribution).