# A Normal distribution inequality

Tags: inequality, normal-distribution, error-function

Denote by $\phi(z)$ and $\Phi(z)$ the density and distribution of a standard Normal variable (mean=0, sd=1), respectively. It appears that for $z > 0$, 
$$
\frac{\phi(z)}{1 - \Phi(z)} < z + \frac{1}{z}
$$
Is there a proof (or disproof) of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar question has been answered [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28751/proof-of-upper-tail-inequality-for-standard-normal-distribution)

Anyway, this is an alternative proof:

Let's rewrite your inequality in the following way

$$\frac{1-\Phi(z)}{\phi(z)}>\frac{z}{1+z^2}$$

$$1-\Phi(z) > \phi(z)\frac{z}{1+z^2}$$

Let's define the following function:

$g(z)=1-\Phi(z)-\phi(z)\frac{z}{1+z^2}$

As:

- $g(0)=\frac{1}{2}>0$
- $g'(z)=-2 \frac{\phi(z)}{(1+z^2)^2}<0$ for every z
- $g(\infty) \rightarrow 0$

thus $g(z)$ is always positive... and this immediately proves what you are requested to do

Comment: Thanks! That's very nice. Is this proof related to other inequality results?