# Inequality on integral of exponential function (related to normal distribution)

Tags: probability, integration

Let $G$ be a standard normal variable, and let $a>0$. Show that

$$P(G>a) \leq exp(-a^2/2)$$

I have tried writing $P(G >a) = (2 \pi)^{-1} exp(-a^2/2) \int_a^{\infty}exp[-(x^2-a^2)/2]dx$ and then completing the square but it did not work. Also seen [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28751/proof-of-upper-tail-inequality-for-standard-normal-distribution), but did not help much either.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(G\gt a)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_a^\infty e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx\lt\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_a^\infty xe^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{a^2}{2}}$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not 100% sure though why your strict inequality holds.

Comment: Minor error.  Holds for $a\gt 1$,  since $x\gt 1$ for entire integral domain. For $0\le a\le 1$, needs a little work.

Comment: For $0\le a\le 1$, $P(G\gt a)\lt \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits _a^\infty xe^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits _a^1 (1-x)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx \lt \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{a^2}{2}}$

Comment: Sorry, but why was again the second integral in your comment smaller than $\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-a^2/2}$?

Comment: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_a^1(1-x)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_a^1(1-a)e^{-\frac{a^2}{2}}dx\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}(1-a)^2e^{-\frac{a^2}{2}}$