# Can you bound exponentially the probability of a normal variable based on the z-score?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, upper-lower-bounds

That is, is there a bound $f(z_a)$ for $P(X > a)$ if the z-score of a is $z_a$?

Is there such a bound that decreases exponentially?

Something like $P(X > a) < c^{z_a}$?

---

Here, a z-score is defined as:

z = (x-μ)/σ

where x is the raw value, μ is the population mean, and σ is the population standard deviation

---

I know there are tables for calculating $P(X > a)$ given a z-score, but they don't help understand what is the function that links z-score and probability

Comment: Can you define what you mean by z score

Comment: Yes, it's well known that if $Z$ is standard gaussian and $t>0$, then $$P(Z\geq t) \leq \frac{1}{t}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-t^2/2}$$ (which is asymptotically tight as $t\to \infty$). The claim then follows for general $X\sim \mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ by applying appropriate transformations.

Comment: @josinalvo it is a "simple exercise" in integration by parts (but a proof of the bound can be found in e.g. the introductory material of hdp by vershynin). On the other hand, the "weaker" bound $P(Z\geq t) \leq e^{-t^2/2}$ can be established by computing a Chernoff bound. This would be sufficient for your purposes

Comment: @Andrew, I presume you mean https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf, but I did not find it there yet

Comment: just found the answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28751/proof-of-upper-tail-inequality-for-standard-normal-distribution

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment but is too long due the links.

Maybe what you are looking for as bound for the probabilities are [Concentration inequalities](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_inequality), which are many like the famous [Chebyshev's](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) or [Markov's](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality) inequalities. But in the case of **independent** random variables, you can use the [Chernoff bound](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound) which in the case of Normal distributed random variables $X\sim N(0,\sigma^2) $ (since you asked about z-scores), is indeed and exponential kind of bound with the shape:
$$P(X<a)\leq e^{-\frac{a^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$